# Ionic 5 Record screen of device?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, screen, record

Is there a way to record the phone's screen on Ionic? I tried a cordova plugin called screenRecrod but it does not work anymore. Any suggestion? I have tried to find a solution for one week but unsuccesfully.

Answer (score 0):

In tour search, don't focus on ionic or cordova, make your search on how to record screen in javascript. And from javascript code you can make you service for recording .

But be aware, some codes are made for specific browsers, so check your results if they are compatible with safari, chrome and ie since these what are used in ionic.

Check this reference below, i used it previously from widows but check if it also works also on device browser or either still works.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

Comment: How can I use javascript code for making my service that can work on typescript and ionic?

Comment: Typescript is base javascript, but typescript is object oriented programing, so javascript works with typescript. In tou function like startCapture() { ... } just avoid using word function infront of function since typescript on rendering ads function keyword, and inside the function startCapture(){ if there is a function like navigator.whatever(function (e){..}) replace function with (e) => {...} .

Comment: The fact is that the really function I need is to record a simple rtsp source (ip camera) and save the stream in the gallery of the phone as .mp4 file. I'm trying to use screen recorder to register the screen during the stream because I'm not able to record directly the stream, I did not find anywhing as library that can do that. Can you help me?